# Pads on the lines

Tags: pcb-design

What's the purpose of all that pads on the picture? [image]

Comment: Breakout board?

Comment: It's a kind of a breakout board.  Somebody could solder LED indicators, pull-up and pull-down resistors, another connector, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As @winny guessed, it's a "prototyping area for in-circuit modifications".  See:
https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/SchmalzTech%20PDFs/ST-RJ45-R-DIN.pdf for a similar product.  Probably not for ethernet since there's not a whole lot to do before the pulse transformer and that doesn't look like a magjack nor does the prototyping area have the correct layout for a pulse transformer.